# Noun starting with vowel vs noun starting without vowel

Tags: java

So the question was "Write a Java program that gets a noun from the keyboard as a String and if the noun starts with a vowel, the program prints "an" followed by the noun, otherwise it prints "a" followed by the noun. For example, if the input noun is "apple" the program prints "an apple" and if the noun is "cat" the program prints "a cat". You may assume all letters are lower case and the vowels are “a, e, i, o, u”. (Hint: the charAt(int index) method of the String class can help)"

And so far I have written out

```
import java.util.Scanner;
   public class Vowels
  {
   public static void main(String[] args)
    {
      Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
      System.out.print("Enter a word");
      int num = reader.nextInt();
      char ch = '1';
   if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' )
    System.out.println("An" + char);
   else 
    System.out.println("A" + char);
    }
  }
```

I feel like I was close to making it work, but honestly even though this is incredibly basic stuff I feel so overwhelmed. I really don't want to rely on googling the answer every time because it doesn't help me learn as much. I'm not even looking for someone to just give me the answer, just if someone could point me in the right direction without going into something too complex for me, that would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Ask yourself why you are doing what you are doing with every single step. What is the purpose of `int num` and `read.neextInt();` when you are never using `num` anyway? You can't print `char`; did you mean `ch`? Why do you want to print `ch`? Why have you stored `'1'` in `ch`? Where is the word that the user entered?

You are overwhelmed because you have no idea what you are doing. You shouldn't try arbitrary things in hopes of accidentally making a program work. Know what you are doing at all times, and know what you don't know so you can ask the right questions and learn.

Answer (score 1):

Okay, so first things first. You print to the console "Enter a word", and then you are accepting `int num`, which does not make sense. Rather, do: `String word = reader.nextLine();`. This is accepting a `String` from the user, which you can use to test if it requires "an" or "a" before the word.

With Java, you can use the `charAt()` method to check the first `char` of the `word` variable that I used above, testing if the first character is a vowel or not. that would look like this: `char ch = word.charAt(0)`. 0 represents the first index in the String.

Then, you can use `System.out.println()` to print "a" or "an" with the `word` variable that is accepted as input.

Answer (score 1):

1. You are reading an integer, change that too `reader.next()`
2. Why is *c* number 1. Change that to be the first letter in the word to `num.charAt(0)`

Somethin like this after the changes:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class Vowels
 {
public static void main(String[] args)
{
  Scanner reader = new      Scanner(System.in);
  System.out.print("Enter a word");
  String num = reader.next();
  char ch = num.charAt(0);
 if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' )
System.out.println("An" + num);
else 
System.out.println("A" + num);
}
}
```

Comment: @Gendarme I edited it, try now? And if it works, remember to tick this answer as solved.

Answer (score 0):

Okay thanks for the assistance, I think I understand a bit more now. The final code ended up being.

```
        import java.util.Scanner;
      public class Vowels
     {
       public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        Scanner reader = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.print("Enter a word ");
        String num = reader.nextLine();
        char ch = num.charAt(0);
       if (ch == 'a' || ch == 'e' || ch == 'i' || ch == 'o' || ch == 'u' )
        System.out.println("An " + num);
       else 
        System.out.println("A " + num);
        }
      }
```